# I'am using css :hover option but my code is not working

Tags: html, css

I'am currently working some code for my website and i came to this problem.I want to change background of paragraph on div's hover but it doesn't seems to works.I found some tutorials and I don't know what is wrong with my code

```
<style>

    .more_news{
        padding:10px;
        border:1px double lightgray;
        width:170px;
        height:100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin:0px; 
    }

    .more_news img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    .more_news p{
        color:green;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        background:gray;
        margin-top:-40px;
        width:170px;
        height:40px;
    }

    .more_news div:hover ~ .more_news p{
        background:red;
    }

</style>

<div class="more_news">
    <img src="images/proba1.png" class="more_news_img">
    <p class="more_news_p">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to change background of paragraph on div's hover but it
>   doesn't seems to works."

You'd just use:

```
.more_news:hover > .more_news_p {
  background:red;
}
```

You were using the [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) `~`, which selects sibling elements after that element.

whereas you actually want to target the paragraph which is a `child` element - hence the use of the direct child selector (`>`)

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bsw2g/)

Comment: @Roman How doesn't it? Your question says when you hover the div you want to highlight the paragraph?

Comment: Ah thank u, it is working now, but can u explain me when i use ~ ? :)

Comment: I go sleep now, will see that tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is select the class and element like so:

```
p.more_news_p:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

No need for `~` or any other [combinator/selector](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

http://jsfiddle.net/7H4XW/

Or, if you want to change the background when you hover over the entire `div` you can do something like this:

```
.more_news:hover p.more_news_p {
    background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qfb9Z/